# Replacing or removing javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty, civicrm

I have some HTML and javascipt that is generated automatically through a URL. This html and javascipt is generated using Smarty templates. Unfortunately, this code that is generated uses a bunch of jQuery, but the references to the jQuery libraries aren't included in the code and so generate errors. I can't change this. Below is an example of the first part of that javascript that generates the error 'Uncaught Reference Error: cj is not defined'

`<script type="text/javascript">
    cj( function() {
      var element_date   = "#birth_date_display";var element_time  = "#birth_date_time";var time_format   = cj( element_time ).attr('timeFormat');
              cj(element_time).timeEntry({ show24Hours : time_format, spinnerImage: '' });
          var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();var alt_field   = '#birth_date';cj( alt_field ).hide();var date_format = cj( alt_field ).attr('format');var altDateFormat = 'mm/dd/yy';
      switch ( date_format ) {
        case 'dd-mm':
        case 'mm/dd':
            altDateFormat = 'mm/dd';
            break;
      }`

What I can do though, is add code onto the end of the file. So I am able to load the relevant libraries and simply enter the same javascript code again, and it works fine.

The problem I am running into is that I am trying to do some styling of the page using jQuery also after the fact. The line below is giving me the problem. Everything gets wrapped fine, but my javascript file just exits on this row,

```
 $("#editrow-email-Primary, #editrow-phone-1-1, #editrow-birth_date").wrapAll("<div class='grid-group personal' />");
```

again with the same error 'Uncaught reference error: cj is not defined. It is the editrow-birth_date div that most of the previous javascript is for as it uses the jQuery UI datepicker. The funny thing is, simply appending the same javascript and jQuery at the end of the file works fine, until I just to .wrapAll. Then it seems to be trying to run something again in the original javascript and generating a new error and exiting.

I'm completely stuck here, and I don't even know how to properly explain what I think is going on. Is there a way that I can remove the original javascript from the code on the fly so that it can't be executed anymore? I don't think so, but I am hoping so as I feel like that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap pulls all of that HTML out of the page and sticks it in HTML built from the param for wrapAll and then you stick the whole bundle back on the page which means you're slapping that same script file back onto the page I assume. Any time a script tag is dropped into a page, all of its JS executes. Now I'm going to edit and make some other suggestions when I've figured wtf is going on with this app but that's your problem with the bonus firing.

Additional:

Okay, so I don't know what Smarty is. Whenever I see a Smarty-related question, something horrifying is going on so I don't even want to know. If you have any control over the app in general, you should be able to add Script tags before jQuery happens. Ideally before this tag gets appended. At the very least, add an empty function called cj before this happens to avoid the errors and then figure where the real cj is so you can plug it back in.

But regardless, if you don't have control of at least most of the HTML, get a stick and hit somebody with it until they  promise to stop making horrifying technology choices and restore control of the HTML to you, the guy who is supposed to be working with the damned HTML and JavaScript to get things running.

Or show them this. I've been at this six years now. These kinds of problems should not be allowed to happen. Technology that robs us of control of our own app gets crumpled up like a paper ball and tossed over your shoulder because you will never get that time back.

Comment: Thank you! So all I did was add a var str = $('#editrow-birth_date').html() to get the html. Then I stripped all of the javascript from the result. And then I ran a $('#editrow-birth_date').html(str) to re-insert it minus all of the javascript before doing the wrapAll. Works like a charm.